# Where can i see hubot logger messages?

Tags: node.js, hubot

I am new to hubot and there i see a statement 
    robot.logger.debug "trying gitio on #{commit.url}"

Can someone tell me where can i see this debug message. I am using ./bin/hubot command to run it. Is there any way to run it in debug mode? so I can see debug messages?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Set the environment variable `HUBOT_LOG_LEVEL` to `debug`. I've been starting `hubot` using this shell script.

<-- startbot.sh -->

```
#!/bin/bash

export HUBOT_HIPCHAT_JID="<your hipchat id>"
export HUBOT_HIPCHAT_PASSWORD="<your password>"
export HUBOT_LOG_LEVEL="debug"
bin/hubot --adapter hipchat
```

Comment: `export HUBOT_LOG_LEVEL="debug"` is all you really need for the debug log.